# Twilio webhook not triggered on incoming calls

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-programmable-voice

I seem to have a problem with Twilio webhooks.
I have a **Trail account**, and have configured webhooks for incoming calls:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyERg.png).

The server and ngrok run OK. When I send a SMS, the webhook is triggered and my server gets the expected request. However when I call the number, the **webhook is not triggered**. The voice says that I have a trail account and that I need to press a key to trigger the webhook, but pressing doesn't help and the call gets dissconnected after 15s. When I added a URL as *CALL STATUS CHANGES webhook*, it was called correctly when the call ended, so the issue seems to be with key presses on incoming calls.
The *call log details* (and my Flask server) confirm that no requests are being made in the case of incoming calls, but show the SMS webhook triggers as expected.

I'm in quite a pickle, since I have no idea how to debug this further. I have called my twilio number with 3 cellphones, one of them being my *Verified Caller ID*, but with no luck.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you wait for the full message to complete before pressing any key?

Comment: Yes, I waited for the message to complete, I've also tried pressing it as fast, as late, and as many times as possible, and only once, and with all the possible buttons. Nothing seems to be making any difference.

Comment: It is a call from and to Poland (+48), if that matters. Tried with multiple carriers and multiple devices.

Comment: Maybe best to open a ticket with Twilio support. Enable voice trace and then send Twilio Support 3 CallSIDs less then 48 hours old and they can investigate. Maybe a DTMF issue, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038021053-Enable-Voice-Trace-for-Troubleshooting-Twilio-Call-Audio-and-DTMF-Issues